# Stable restrictions of sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, stability

Let $X$ be a projective variety and $Y$ a subvariety.

If $E$ is a stable sheaf on $X$, then under certain circumstances (e.g. the theorems of Flenner, Mehta-Ramanathan, Bogomolov) the restriction $E|_Y$ is also stable. Restriction then induces a map between the moduli space of stable sheaves on $X$ to the moduli space of stable sheaves on $Y$. My question is this:

> What is known about this map? For example, what is the dimension of its image?

I'd be interested in any answer, including answers with stringent restrictions on $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: As far as I know the only stability notion that is well behaved under restriction to hyperplane sections
is Mumford semistability

Comment: You must take $Y$ in an  ample linear system